# Strange behavior in Library API call (NET and  C++)

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I have a thirt pary API. It simply stream media to given ip-port(read media from a capture device).

When I use that API in a Windows Form Application, it works. But when i call this API in a Console or Windows Service, it does not give any error but does not work[ does not stream ]: It seems that it does not take stream data from device.

The only difference betwween is that One Applications is Windows Form Application, the other is not..
There is really no difference other than this.

**What kind of dependency may cause such a thing? Any idea ?**

*PS: The API is written in C++. I use that API in NET(C++/CLI)*

For Example:

```
// Works in Windows Form Application

System::Void startButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{

    MyAPI->Start();
}
System::Void stopButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 
{
    MyAPI->Stop();
}
```

but ....

```
// Not Work In Console or Windows Service

 MyAPI->Start();

 Console::WriteLine("Streaming started.Press enter to exit");
 Console::Read();

 MyAPI->Stop();

Console::WriteLine("Streaming stopped");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of a UI-application, there's always a message queue. In a console application, the is not. The 3rd party software might post messages to the message queue that is not there in the console-application. Doing so might cause unpredictable program behaviour. Try calling GetMessage() from the win api before the communication is started.

Comment: Is there simple way to simulate-emit that message queue into  console or windows service application?

Comment: If the 3rd party api supplies a service entry point that you can call when a message is received, yes. If the 3rd party creates a hidden window to receive the messages, again: yes. If the 3rd party api supplies a function that runs a message loop with call back facility: yes. See the discusion on GetMessage() win api function on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks. Will check GetMessage()

Comment: @6.45.Vapuru : Given that you're already using managed code, you may be able to save yourself some work by using the [`System::Windows::Forms::NativeWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.aspx) class instead of dealing with message dispatch manually.

Answer (score 1):

The third party API probably depends internally on Windows event dispatching, which a console app will not do (by default, I believe you can set up event dispatching within a console app).

Comment: +1.  Also If you are running as a service, you have entirely different privileges and are running in a different user session (session 0, actually).  You can set up services to run under a specific user context to fix most of these issues via Control Panel / Administrative Tools / Services.

Comment: @antlersoft Thanks...It may be..How to set up event dispatching within a console app? Or this should be asked as an diffferent question?

Comment: @AresAvatar Thanks .But my windows services are OK. There is no privileges problems.

Comment: I found this question that discusses dispatcher in a console app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683617/dispatcher-checkaccess-isnt-working-from-my-console-application-is-there-a-be